# How do I combine a PDF with another continuous function and then do a sum product?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I haven't done math in awhile so am a bit fuzzy on how to set up the problem. Let's say there's a test that students take and they can score anywhere between 0 and 10000. Let's say the distribution of test scores follows a Beta PDF, let's call this function PDF(X).  And let's say there are 200 students.

There's also another function:

```
y = b0 + b1X + b2X^2
```

That tells us, for each score, what the probability is a student makes it to college.

I want to calculate two things.

- What is the total expected number of students that make it to college in a class
  of 200?
- What is the average score for the students that make it to college?

In a discrete world, this is easy, just do sum product. I would first, multiply each value in a PMF, by the chance of a student making it to college, and then times the total number of students, to get the number of students that make it to college. It would be something like:

```
sumproduct(PMF(X), b0 + b1X + b2X^2) * 200
```

In other words, let's say 5% of students score 100, and if you score 100, you have a 20% chance of making it to college. That means 10 students score 100, and only 2 of those that scored 100 make it to college. We do that for each X value, add it all up, to get the number of students that make it to college.  Using the same concept, the mean score of those that make it college would be something like the following.  Note that the sumproduct in the numerator has X itself in it as well:

```
(sumproduct(PMF(X), b0 + b1X + b2X^2, X) * 200) / 
(sumproduct(PMF(X), b0 + b1X + b2X^2) * 200)
```

In continuous world, I believe the concept is the same, but we use a PDF instead of PMF and also need to do an integral. But I'm not sure how to set up the integral for the two questions. To find the expected number of students going to college, would it just be:

```
IntegralBetween0And10000(PDF(X) *(b0 + b1X + b2X^2)) * 200
```

And then for the average test score of those going to college:

```
(IntegralBetween0And10000(PDF(X)  * (b0 + b1X + b2X^2) * X) * 200) / 
(IntegralBetween0And10000(PDF(X) *(b0 + b1X + b2X^2)) * 200)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking a beta distribution is supported in $[0,1]$ but presumably you could multiply this by $10000$.  A probability cannot exceed $1$.  The expected number of students making it to college would the probability of an individual student making it (the same for each student) multiplied by the number of students.

Comment: You do not need the `* 200` in your final expression in the numerator or denominator, and in any case they cancel.  Otherwise you approach seems reasonable.

Comment: yeah, but i believe i can transform the beta distribution using scale and loc parameters.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ represent a student's test score, with pdf $f(x)$ for $a \le x \le b$.  Let $g(x) = \mathbb P[C \mid X = x]$ be the conditional probability of making it to college ($C$) given a test score of $x$.  Then
the probability of a student making it to college  is
$$ \mathbb P[C] = \int_a^b g(x) f(x)\; dx$$
and the average score of the students that make it to college is

$$ \dfrac{\int_a^b x g(x) f(x)\; dx}{\int_a^b g(x) f(x)\; dx} $$

Comment: ah, so it is just multiplying the functions together and then taking the integral.  thanks!